# How can I test an engines controller in my main application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Inside my engine, I have something like:

```
class Report
  has_many :measures
end
class Measure; end
```

Have inside my main application, I decorated `Measure` to have a default scope. This ended up breaking the `ReportsController` inside of my engine.

Is there a way I can test this? I.e. some way of running the controller tests for all of my engines inside the main application?

Comment: Is your models inside the engine namespaced? Because what you did was monkey patch the `Measure` class inside the engine

Comment: Yes, it is name spaced. I'm not sure what you're getting at – my monkey patch works, I'm just wondering how to test it